# Mathematica Manipulate, Plot, Piecewise

Tags: plotting, manipulate, piecewise

I have two functions `h2` and `v2` that I need to graph using `Piecewise` and be able to manipulate certain variables in the equations. Whatever I try, my code returns a blank plot.

```
Manipulate[
Plot[
Piecewise[
{{{h2[t], t0 < t}, 0},
{{v2[t], 0 < t < t0}, 0}}],
{t, 0, 500}],
{{t, 0, Time}, 0, 500},
{{A, 200, Alpha}, 0, 500},
{{B, 1, Bravo}, 0, 50},
{{C, 0.5, Charlie}, 0, 50},
{{D, 0.1, Delta}, 0, 1}]
```

I know that both of my functions `h2` and `v2` are correct.

As you can see, `v2` starts at `t=0` and ends at `t=t0`, and `h2` starts at `t=t0`.

I tried removing the `t` `Manipulator` to no avail.

Here are equations `v2` and `h2`:

```
v2[t] = -((C g)/D) - g (-(C/D) + t) + A Log[(D + B)/B]

h2[t] = (A C)/D - (C^2 g)/(2 D^2) - (g t^2)/2 - 
(A B Log[(C + B)/B])/D + A t Log[(C + B)/B]
```

Comment: You have a `t` as the independent variable inside the `Plot` command and a `t` as a `Manipulate`d variable. There might be some conflict there. Otherwise, without the definitions of `h2[t]` and `v2[t]`, it's hard to know what's going wrong. Have you tried coming up with a simpler version first that doesn't have so many moving parts (i.e. so many parameters) so that you can narrow in on what might be the issue? That's good trouble-shooting practice.

Comment: You still have a problem with `t` and `t0`. I'm guessing that `{{t, 0, Time}, 0, 500}` should be `{{t0, 0, Time}, 0, 500}`?

Comment: There are other problems. Don't use capital letters for user-defined symbols in *Mathematica*, because all built-in functions are capitalized. For instance, both `C` and `D` are reserved symbols in *Mathematica*. Perhaps first try to just plot the function with a set of parameters first; once you get that working, *then* try the `Manipulate`. Also, `g` is undefined! Is it a number or did you mean to put it in as a `Manipulate`d variable? Also, your syntax for `Piecewise` is wrong. Also, your definitions for `v2` and `h2` should look like `h2[t_]` and `v2[t_]`.

Comment: Basically, you need to spend some time with the very helpful *Mathematica* documentation to figure out correct *Mathematica* syntax, and you need to spend some time doing the simple things first, and then building up more complicated code once you have the simpler code working.

Comment: I've narrowed it down to my piecewise function being incorrect. Any help on that? I've read the documentation but didn't make much sense of it.

Comment: `Piecewise[{{h2[t], t0 < t}, {v2[t], 0 < t < t0}}]`?

Comment: Okay I've got the plotting all sorted however now Mathematica is calculating an equation incorrectly.

I've input values of A,B,C,D,g and the correct value for t0. My calculator gives me the correct value substituting the variables into the mathematica piecewise equation, however mathematica is way off.

Comment: @chris493 then please update your question accordingly. Just to be sure: you are aware that `Log` is the natural (Euler's) logarithm, correct? Many other systems have this as the base-10 logarithm. Additionally `C` and `D` are system symbols and should not be used for your own variables.

Comment: I've changed the C and D variables in my code however there's no difference. I'll look into the natural log.